# Typescript is showing error if I try to access the property value dynamically using square brackets in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13

**How to Fix** *No index signature with a parameter of type 'string'* **issue in Angular**

Getting ESLint error here : Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Client'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Row'

dynamic-table.component.html

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let i of headers">
      {{i.name}}
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <td *ngFor="let head of headers">
      {{row[head.name]}} <!-- Getting ESLint error here : Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Client'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Row'. -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

dynamic-table.component.ts

```js
interface Header {
 displayName: string,
 name: string
}

interface Row {
 empId: string,
 empName: string,
 salary: string
}

@Component({
  selector: "dynamic-table",
  templateUrl: "./dynamic-table.component.html",
  styleUrls: []
})
export class DynamicTableComponent {
  title = "Dynamic Table";

  headers: Header[] = [];
  rows: Row[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.headers = [
      {
        displayName: "Emp Name",
        name: "empName"
      },
      {
        displayName: "Emp ID",
        name: "empId"
      },
      {
        displayName: "Salary",
        name: "salary"
      }
    ];
    this.rows = [
      {
        empId: "1",
        empName: "red",
        salary: "10000"
      },
      {
        empId: "1",
        empName: "red",
        salary: "50000"
      },
      {
        empId: "1",
        empName: "red",
        salary: "30000"
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g3yktx?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: Yes in Stackblitz it is not showing that linter issue, event in Codesandbox also it is not able to reproduce the issue. it appears only in VSCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 13 Angular CLI enables TypeScript `strict` mode on newly created projects. That enables (among other) the [noImplicitAny](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) flag.

Since `header.name` could be any string TypeScript has no way to know the type of `row[header.name]` so it's assigning it to `any` (and is complaining about that).

To solve the issue you can do any of the followings:

(1) declare an index signature on your `Row` interface:

```
interface Row {
  [key: string]: string,
  empId: string,
  empName: string,
  salary: string
}
```

Here you're telling TS that any property on `Row` accessed through a string will have a `string` type.

(2) restrict the type of `Header.name` to a literal union of `Row`'s keys:

```
interface Header {
    displayName: string,
    name: keyof Row
}
```

Here you're declaring the type of `Header.name` as `"empId" | "empName" | "salary"` (no other value will be allowed).

(3) Disable the `noImplicitAny` flag by setting `"noImplicitAny": false` in your `tsconfig.json` (obviously this will disable the check at all).